# Accessing form.cleaned_data in get method in class based views

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a situation where I should first display a form to the user where the user fill in two fields and after that base on the form fields I query database and show the user a list of objects. 
But the problem is I use class based views and I can't access to the cleaned data in my get method. I know that the forms must be handled in post methods not get methods so I can't process form in my get method. 
Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
class IncomeTransactionReport(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # here I get form from post request
        form = IncomeReportForm(request.POST)
        # if form is valid redirect user to the same page to show the results based on the filled
        # in form  fields 'from_date' and 'to_date'
        if form.is_valid():
            from_date = form.cleaned_data['from_date']
            to_date = form.cleaned_data['to_date']
            return redirect('income_report')
        # else render the same page with the form and form errors
        else:
            error_message = 'Please solve the error and try again'
            return render(request, 'report_income.html', context={'error_message': error_message,
            'form': form}, status=422)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # here I need to access 'from_date' and 'to_date' to query the database and show the results
        # in paginated pages to the user
        if from_date != None and to_date != None:
            incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=user,
            date__gte=datetime.date.fromisoformat(from_date),
            date__lte=datetime.date.fromisoformat(to_date)).all()
        elif from_date != None:
            incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=user,
            date__gte=datetime.date.fromisoformat(from_date),
            date__lte=datetime.date.fromisoformat(from_date) + \
            relativedelta.relativedelta(months=+1)).all()
        else:
            incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=user).all()
        page = request.POST.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(incomes, 5)
        try:
            incomes = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            incomes = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            incomes = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        message = 'This is your requested list of incomes'
        # here I return the results
        return render(request, 'report_income.html', {'message': message, 'incomes': incomes})
```

I you need more information please let me know to post it here.

Comment: Well there is a reason why in you "can't access" the clened_data in get. cleaned_data in simple words is a dictionary that gets the value of filled out form - in `get()` you usually just present the blank form so there is no data you get from user therefore cleaned_data use is `get()` is kind of nonsense. If you need more in-depth info just let me know because its much more complex than that. It's just to help you understand it should work

Comment: I need those information by user. So what is the proper way to do this task? @quqa123

Comment: yea I'll post it as an anwser in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep search and thinking I found out that the best thing to do is to put form cleaned data in session and access it in other method such as get method.

Answer (score 3):

To anwser your question I'll just describe proper form processing in django. But for the love of god please don't post such questions before reading the documentation that perfectly explayins everything [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/)
This is the example of how to proccess a view that has a form in it:

```
SomeClassBasedView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'some_template.html'

    def get(self, request):
        # some custom get processing
        form = SomeForm()  # inhereting form.Form or models.ModelForm
        context = { 'form': form,
                    # other context
                   }
        return render(request, self.template, context)

    def post(self, request):

        # this works like 'get data from user and populate form'
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # now cleaned_data is created by is_valid
            # example:
            user_age = form.cleaned_data['age']
            # some other form proccessing
            context = {
                'form': SomeForm(),
                # other context
            }
            return render(request, self.template, context)

        # if there were errors in form
        # we have to display same page with errors
        context = {
            'form': form,
            # other context
        }
        return render(request, self.template, context)
```

Comment: thanks! that really cheered me up, im trying to help as well I as I can

Comment: Somebody thought it fit to reduce your rep tally by "1". Why?

Comment: The best solution so far on this site. **Keep it up.**